# How to run interactive portal in Android webview on various resolutions and physical sizes of screen?

Tags: java, android, android-webview, screen-resolution, hybrid-mobile-app

I've got Android app with full screen web view displaying HTML5/JS/CSS portal which acts as set of widgets (OSD menu). Webview is transparent and there is a Javascript API implemented in Android app for interaction between webview and native part.
I would like to be able to run this app successfully on any Android device in terms of physical size and resolution. Initial resolution where app was tested and run OK was 10" tablet, 1280 x 800 pixels.
If I run this app on smaller screens, like 7" or even 5", webview displayed kind of zoomed in top left corner of portal. I've learnt to use following to start with zoomed out complete view:

```
mBrowser.getSettings().setLoadWithOverviewMode(true);
mBrowser.getSettings().setUseWideViewPort(true);
```

This has two issues for me, which I need to solve:

1. portal includes also gestures and buttons to click. Gestures seem to work (swipe right and left), but buttons inside of widgets don't react on single click. I don't set any touch listener, everything should be handled by portal in webview. How to make these buttons work?
2. With having .setUseWideViewPort(true); in place, there is unnecessary double tap allowed, which does zoom in & out. How to disable this without spoiling point no. 1?